# Toxicity of Mercury (II) Iodide and dicopper (I) tetraiodomercurate (II)

Tags: coordination-compounds, safety, mercury

This is a continuation from my [previous post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149787/how-to-use-sodium-thiosulfate-for-fixing-dicopper-i-tetraiodomercurate-ii).

Could you please give me some info on the toxicity of compounds $\ce{HgI2}$ and $\ce{Cu2[HgI4]}$? I found on sigmaaldrich.com that these are very dangerous but could not find any information on the dosages for skin contact and swallowing.

Comment: You should check the msds of the compounds. For e.g. HgI2:. https://fscimage.fishersci.com/msds/13820.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the @Nilay Ghosh recommendation, I found [an SDS sheet](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=RU&language=en&productNumber=466379&brand=ALDRICH&PageToGoToURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Faldrich%2F466379%3Flang%3Den) for $\ce{Cu2[HgI4]}$ and there is [SDS](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=RU&language=en&productNumber=221090&brand=SIGALD&PageToGoToURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%3Fterm%3D7774-29-0%26interface%3DCAS%2520No.%26N%3D0%26mode%3Dpartialmaxfocus%3Dproduct%26lang%3Den%26region%3DRU%26focus%3Dproduct%26gclid%3DCj0KCQjwgtWDBhDZARIsADEKwgNWnKjfBZcewOq1fzZ5SENdKvCry40DAd5jKB8MBoPFcm0Weuk2k90aArFjEALw_wcB) for $\ce{HgI2}$.

**For $\ce{Cu2[HgI4]}$:**

- Acute toxicity estimate Oral (Expert judgment): 5,1 mg/kg
- Acute toxicity estimate Inhalation (Expert judgment) 4 h: 0,051 mg/l
- Acute toxicity estimate Dermal (Expert judgment): 5,1 mg/kg

**For $\ce{HgI2}$:**

- LD50 oral rat: 18 mg/kg
- Acute toxicity estimate Inhalation (Expert judgment) 4 h: 0,051 mg/l
- Acute toxicity estimate Dermal (Expert judgment): 5,1 mg/kg